# How to add column to dataframe with unequal length in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame and I want to add an extra column based on a pattern of an other column, but with unequal length of a numeric list.

```
class(mylist)
[1] "numeric"

mylist 
 [1]  90 100  97 100  93 100  90 100 100 100 100 100 100 100  96 100 100 100 100 100
```

This is my data.frame, i just show part of it

```
df[16:26,]
# A tibble: 11 × 9
   parent  node branch.length label     isTip      x     y  branch angle
    <int> <int>         <dbl> <chr>     <lgl>  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1     30    16     0.0000117 sample-59 TRUE  0.0213 15    0.0213  257. 
 2     39    17     0.0000179 sample-62 TRUE  0.0213  4    0.0213   68.6
 3     32    18     0.0000212 sample-63 TRUE  0.0213  3    0.0213   51.4
 4     40    19     0.0000147 sample-68 TRUE  0.0213  5    0.0213   85.7
 5     40    20     0.0000147 sample-69 TRUE  0.0213  6    0.0213  103. 
 6     28    21     0.00630   sample-5  TRUE  0.0213 11    0.0181  189. 
 7     22    22     0         NA        FALSE 0       8.20 0       140. 
 8     22    23     0.0143    NA        FALSE 0.0143 13.9  0.00715 239. 
 9     22    24     0.0129    NA        FALSE 0.0129  2.47 0.00645  42.3
10     24    25     0.000115  NA        FALSE 0.0130  3.94 0.0130   67.5
11     25    26     0.00241   NA        FALSE 0.0154  5.88 0.0142  101.
```

So, I want to add mylist to the end of the data frame, but only with those rows with FALSE in isTip column.

I usually do this like:

Filter

```
dfisTip <- filter(df, isTip == FALSE)
```

add the list as column (btp)

```
dfisTip$btp <- mylist
```

and join the dataframes

```
df <- left_join(df, dfisTip)
Joining, by = c("parent", "node", "branch.length", "label", "isTip", "x", "y", "branch", "angle")



df[16:26, ]
# A tibble: 11 × 10
   parent  node branch.length label     isTip      x     y  branch angle   btp
    <int> <int>         <dbl> <chr>     <lgl>  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     30    16     0.0000117 sample-59 TRUE  0.0213 15    0.0213  257.     NA
 2     39    17     0.0000179 sample-62 TRUE  0.0213  4    0.0213   68.6    NA
 3     32    18     0.0000212 sample-63 TRUE  0.0213  3    0.0213   51.4    NA
 4     40    19     0.0000147 sample-68 TRUE  0.0213  5    0.0213   85.7    NA
 5     40    20     0.0000147 sample-69 TRUE  0.0213  6    0.0213  103.     NA
 6     28    21     0.00630   sample-5  TRUE  0.0213 11    0.0181  189.     NA
 7     22    22     0         NA        FALSE 0       8.20 0       140.     90
 8     22    23     0.0143    NA        FALSE 0.0143 13.9  0.00715 239.    100
 9     22    24     0.0129    NA        FALSE 0.0129  2.47 0.00645  42.3    97
10     24    25     0.000115  NA        FALSE 0.0130  3.94 0.0130   67.5   100
11     25    26     0.00241   NA        FALSE 0.0154  5.88 0.0142  101.     93
```

All the rows with TRUE in isTip column have NA in btp column, and those with FALSE have the number!!

I just was wonder if it is any other simple way to do it????

Thanks!!!

Comment: I'd strongly encourage you to not call regular atomic vectors "lists". A `list` is it's own class, and calling non-lists lists can cause confustion.

Comment: I would suggest to add your data as given by `dput`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We generally index data frames with `data[rows, columns]`. If you want to assign `mylist` to the `"btp"` column for the rows where `isTip == FALSE` (which we'll write as `!isTip`), then you can do it like this:

```
df[!isTip, "btp"] <- mylist
```

`mylist` will need to be the correct length.

Or, in `dplyr`, you could do this without splitting your data (though I prefer the direct assignment above).

```
df %>%
  left_join(data.frame(isTip = FALSE, btp = mylist), by = "isTip")
```

Comment: thanks so much, the first option is simple and easy to remember. And thanks for the advise with the list term. Thanks !!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are right - it is not necessary to split and rejoin the data. Here is an example with the iris dataset:

```r
data("iris")

vector_length_virginica  <- c(1:50)
iris$newcol[iris$Species=="virginica"]  <- vector_length_virginica
```

Now the new column `newcol` contains the values of the vector (not list) `vector_length_virginica` where `Species=="viriginica")`, and the rest of the values in that column are `NA`.